# How to find files their names, name of files are in one file?

Tags: grep, find, filenames

I know how to find and concatinate pdf file. I did with the follwoing code.

```
pdfunite *.pdf output.pdf
```

But the problem is I have list of file names in one file say filenames.txt and I would like to search these files in the same folder and combine only these files.
I tried to search on internet but could not find similar solution.
I tried to use grep -wFf option to find

```
find | grep -wFf "fileames.txt\*.pdf" cat *.pdf
```

Does anybody have idea how can I do it?
name file is as follows:

```
CSAI_isotig00407:342-556
CSAI_isotig00408:342-556
.
.
```

while the pdf files are with these name followed by 1,2,3.pdf

```
CSAI_isotig00407:342-556_1.pdf
CSAI_isotig00408:342-556_2.pdf
```

Comment: Add an extract of this file to your question.

Comment: Actually the list in name file has more then one pdf file for each. These are differentiated with some numbers in the after the file name(that are in name file)

Comment: So my intention is to take the first entry from the txt file and find all the pdf files that start with this name and do the same for all the entries in txt file.

Comment: and finlly merg all these files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdfunite $(sed 's/$/_*.pdf/' filenames.txt) output.pdf`

So if `filenames.txt` contains

```
CSAI_isotig00407:342-556
CSAI_isotig00408:342-556
```

That command will effectively do

```
pdfunite CSAI_isotig00407:342-556_*.pdf CSAI_isotig00408:342-556_*.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: The $(...) sequence will run the mentioned command (in this case the sed command) and place the output on the command line. The sed statement will add an -*.pdf to the end of every line in the filenames.txt file.  Combine the two and you get what you want :-)